# Feed Dialog posts not showing on the news feed

Tags: facebook, post, feed

I'm using Feed Dialog to create a post from my website's micro app onto a user's facebook wall/feed. However, whenever I make the post from my website, the post shows up on my wall, but never in the news feed. I have checked & confirmed with friends, and my own account. The posts, while visible on my wall, do not appear in the news feed at all. None of these friends are blocked or have blocked my posts, which I have confirmed by going over there settings with them in person, some of these friends are in fact family which have full access to all my profile elements. For whatever reason the posts aren't showing up. I scoured google and found only two questions that matched mine exactly with no answers. The comments I know are off, they are just for me and I understand them, my site's urls and app codes are removed.

The posts work, except they never appear on the feed. Can anyone explain this, what am I doing wrong?

THANKS :D

### Here is the code for the postToFeed function

```
                <div id='fb-root'></div>
                <script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US     /all.js'></script>
                <!--<p><a onclick='postToFeed(); return false;'>Post to Feed</a></p>-->
                <p id='msg'></p>
                <!-- REQUIRED -->
                <script>FB.init({appId: "SECRET", status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
                //This is the functional trigger for Feed Dialogue using FB.ui
                function postToFeed() {
                        // vars pull the data from the form based on the id's of each input element
                        var linkStr = document.getElementById('link').value;
                        var nameStr = document.getElementById('mname').value;
                        var descStr1 = document.getElementById('hr').value;
                        var descStr2 = document.getElementById('life').value;
                        var descStr3 = document.getElementById('party').value;
                        var descStr4 = document.getElementById('weap').value;
                        var descStr5 = document.getElementById('click').value;
                        var descStr6 = document.getElementById('ttier').value;
                        var descStr7 = document.getElementById('mn').value;

                            // Determine if the monster is critical based on the hours variable
                            if (descStr1 < "25") {
                                    var critStr = "CRITICAL"
                                    var pic = "(my site URL"
                                }
                            else { 
                                    var critStr = ""
                                    var pic = "(mysite URL)"
                                }
                            // Build the post using variable data pulled from form
                            var obj = {
                                method: 'feed', 
                                link: linkStr,
                                picture: pic,
                                name: nameStr + ' ' + critStr,
                                description: 'Time Left:' + descStr1 + ':' + descStr7 + 'Hrs | Top Tier Full?: ' + descStr6 + ' | Life Left:' + descStr2 + '% | Party/Defence:' + descStr3 + '% | # of Weapons Launched: ' + descStr4 + ' | Clicks for next: ' + descStr5
                            };
                        // Check if posted
                        function callback(response) {

                            document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];   

                            }
                                FB.ui(obj, callback);

                            }

        </script>
```

Comment: I've experiencing the same problem and really want to see what's going on here

Comment: I can host the page in both fanpage tab and application canvas, what is interesting is when user invoke share dialog from application canvas, the share can enter the news feed while if the share dialog is invoked from the tab page, it only appear in the timeline but not the news feed. I have a mobile page where people can invoke share dialog also, but still the share won't enter news feed if share dialog is invoked there.